# Using += Or Something Like That In MySql Update Query

Tags: c#, mysql

Everything was explained in the title.

I am Using This Code :

```
            foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
            {
                string charactername = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
                cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "update entities set ConquerPoints ='1' where Name ='" + charactername + "';";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

It is Working But It Just Sets It To 1

My Question is :

If It Is  For Example : 5

How To Set It To +10  [15]

Comment: You told it to set it to 1 in the SQL statement, yet you sound surprised that's what it did?  If you want to increment the value, do something like this in your update:  `SET ConquerPoints = ConquerPoints + 10`, or whatever value you're increasing it by.

Comment: Thanks For Answering My Question Tim I Didn't say I am Surprised I Just Wanted To Know The Query For My needed Action And Thanks It Has Worked .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand your question completely, AS per my  assumption you might be trying to do following ......

1. Increase the value of column 'ConquerPoints' by 10. In that case you need to change your code as follows :

   ```
   cmd.CommandText = "update entities set ConquerPoints = ConquerPoints + 10 where Name ='" + charactername + "';";
   ```